# "reversing pump" in closed water circuit, can water pumped reach further than wave length?

Tags: pumps, pipelines, water-pressure, hydrodynamics

In a closed water circuit with a reversing pump. If the wavelength of how far water pressure wave (positive and negative) reaches during one pump/suction cycle is much shorter than the length of the pipe circuit. Does the pressure waves still reach through the whole circuit. And are multiple pressure waves output into the same circuit, after one another, at the same time?

Comment: I really don't understand what this means

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the pressure wave will propagate at approximately 1500 m/s, reach everywhere, and come back, interfering with itself, unless there is a damper in the piping like a shock absorber.

Let's say your pipe section after the pump is 200 meters long and your pump frequency is 2000 HZ. So the wavelength in cold water is

$ wave_l= 1500/2000 = 0.75 m.$

It will travel at a speed of 1500 m/s throughout the network and reflect back on itself, reaching the end of the section in

$ 200/1500=1/7.5 seconds.$

The wave will affect the plumbing itself and cause vibrations! In some old buildings, the opening and closing of a valve will cause loud vibrations in the plumbing, which is a nuisance.

Comment: Thanks. Replying from other account here (had planned to merge the guest account I created quickly when asking but apparently have to be on same browser for that). Just to clarify for my own understanding. This means I could output something like 200/0.75 waves into the pipe that are all propagating at the same time, sequentially, covering the 200 meters in total? And each reaching the end after 1/7.5 seconds after it was input, and 0.75/1500 = 1/2000 seconds after the previous one?

Comment: @BipedalJoe, yes. exactly. think of ultrasound imaging. the waves hit an organ and reflect back and are captured by the transducer.

Comment: thanks. or any sound wave. managed to figure that out too. for some reason, I had trouble conceptually seeing it for water in a pipe but I guess it is longitudinal waves there too.